# How to manage a project on ruby on rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project-management, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a large ruby on rails 2.3 which was now a disaster because of the slowness and many bugs. I'm the only programmer and every day I've done debugging and tearing my hair off because of this. The users are already using the product but so many bugs and data are scattered.

I was employed without prior knowledge of project development and management. Now I'm suffering of having more overtime and a crisis on my codes to be fixed.

And also I've created this app while learning rails so there are codes there that became stranger to me.

What should I do? 
What are your suggestions?
What books do I need to read about more?

Please I need some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to recommend you upgrade to Rails 3. Especially since there are many newer features and some things are simplified, and it would ease future maintainability.

However, unfortunately, I am hesitant to (or rather simply cannot) actually recommend that given that you already have much more on your hands.

In this case, the best thing you can do is to start writing tests. If there are so many bugs, I have to assume that either you have no tests or your have an incomplete test suite. Tests will help to give you confidence that you do not break anything when you try to fix something else.

The default rails test framework can be found at the [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html). Having said that, many people prefer the [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) testing framework. There are indeed shortcomings of the default Rails testing framework (notably the fragility of fixtures - try get a [factory gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_fixture_replacement), and other features such as mocks and expectations, and nested contexts).

You should read up on the testing frameworks, and maybe try it a bit. Pick one testing framework early on however, and start testing everything!

Perhaps when you become more confident in your test suite and have fixed the most important bugs, you should think more about a path to upgrading Rails - because all the gems will march on, and gradually drop support for Rails 2.3, which means you will be using increasingly old gems which may no be well supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can now see a fault on my programming where I have ignored tested completely in my learning. I was already put on the battlefield(Actual client work) when still learning rails. I will soon be able to do this thing if I had more time. But I have 14 days to fix everything and learn testing procedures.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understood, you are asking for project managment tips and tools how to get a rails project under control.

I believe first thing you need to is stabilize the project. To do this, you will need to minimize the bugs and chart the required work.

I see two complementary approaches for this:

- use a task/bug tracking tool
- start using cucumber for testing

#### Task/bug tracking

This is very important, because you will need some kind of list that itemizes all bugs.

Sometimes users discover a bug, and suddenly you have to drop everything, because at that moment, that single bug is the most important bug ever, and needs to be solved immediately.
However, if you would ask them outright if this means the bugs you are fixing are more or less important, the answer could be different.

So it is in your advantage if there is a clear way to let the user participate in that decision process. If there is a shared bug-list, users can also follow the current state (what you are working on), they can indicate/choose which bugs are more important for them.

Secondly: having a list of items(work/tasks/outstanding bugs/...) will also help you planning the work.

There are a lot of options to some kind of bug-tracking, but some easy/pragmatic/free suggestions are

- checkout trello
- use the issues from github

Tracking the bugs/tasks will give you the feeling you gain control of your project, and furthermore: it will make this also more visible to your client.

#### Cucumber

When fixing bugs there is always the danger to introduce new bugs, definitely in a project that is originally not your own.

In a project where there are next to no tests, I always propose to start with cucumber. Cucumber has a few advantages:

- it tests your application/website from the outside in: no need to understand the code fully, you just need to know what the application should do. If I click this link, it should take me to that page.
- it is really easy to write tests in cucumber, and you get test-coverage really quickly
- as a bonus, your `test-code` is readable, which you could show your clients/users, and they would actually understand what is covered by the tests (and could correct/improve it).

#### Upgrading or not?

I personally believe your first step should be stabilizing the project and minimize/remove all bugs. Whilst upgrading to rails 3 would be a huge improvement, it is not a straightforward process. There are good guidelines, but if you do it now, you will have no idea if a bug was introduced during the upgrade, or existed before. First get your code quality in order, and then do the upgrade.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have 14 days to fix and make everything going smooth. Can this be possible for me to

Comment: I think you should be able to get far. Create an inventory of the bugs, prioritize them, and start with the most important bugs first. For each bug, create a cucumber script (`feature`) that fails first. And then just work the list. If you have never done cucumber, maybe try to find some local assistance (pair-programming) for a few hours to get you kick started. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have never done cucumber. I started rails as I develop the system. Only now I realize the huge difference in using unit-testing or testing etc.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to recommend cucumber. To me, it is excessively verbose and unnecessary. It is sufficient to stick with Unit::Test or RSpec. Using cucumber just adds another layer of unnecessary test documentation to maintain. Comments with clear tests (in Unit::Test or Rspec) are enough to document what is being tested.

Comment: Well I disagree. If it is purely cucumber syntax, check out steak. But otherwise imho it is much easier, because you are testing at a much higher level. In unit tests you are testing all components as much as possible in isolation. This means testing the controller and mocking/stubbing models, testing models by themselves, testing the routing ... And those are a lot of work to get good full coverage. Imo this is very valuable, but if you are just starting I think it is easier to get coverage using cucumber/steak. JKust my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the thing you are asking is completely depending on how much refactoring you need to clean up the whole project. **If you have enough time** in your hand to clean it up completely. I would suggest following steps:

- **Getting Ready**

  - Get the visualization of the whole project. What is required and what is not required.
  - Define your resources and relation between them properly.
  - Use proper **RESTful routing**.
  - Decide the test tools and frameworks like `cucumber`, `rspec`, `factory girl` etc.
- **Plan of Action**

  - Decide (if possible, as a team) that what are the **minimum** or **necessary** changes required.
  - Isolate all the components in different groups so that each group can be refactored individually. Smaller groups are preferred.
  - Decide test cases.
  - Break down tasks into as much as small size possible.
  - Make sure to keep your test coverage more than 90%.

This process will take around 4-5 months for a medium scale project for a team of 4 members.

Let us know if you have any specific confusion.

Comment: Sadly I was the only one who is doing the project. I can't seem to afford 4-5 months time. Since I have developed it users are already using at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no quick fix in your current solution. If you seriously consider an upgrade, it will take time to fill in the missing tests if you haven't been writing them, pick up the testing frameworks on top of Rails 3, and work out the necessary data migration once you are ready to flip the switch.

The other option is to continue with Rails 2.x, which isn't completely unfathomable although the support avenues will be much more limited. You still need to work in the tests as a first priority and understand the various nuances that are present in the existing application.

For your scenario (one-man racket with little to no prior experience), I feel that sticking with what you have and improving the testability up to the point where you would feel an upgrade is worthwhile, would be the prudent action. No matter which course of action you would take, be prepared to put in quite a bit of work in the short-to-middle term (but such is the case of accumulating technical debt).

Comment: I also want to upgrade but since I haven't stabilize the system yet. Also I the system is running slow.

Answer (score 0):

What to read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/ Start with chapters about debugging and performance testing.

Forget about upgrading to Rails 3 for now, at this moment it would only introduce many more bugs and probably lots of problems with legacy gems and plugins. And don't forget that you need ruby 1.9 in order to upgrade to rails 3 - yet another batch of problems.

Adding tests is a good idea, as *ronalchn* suggested. I'd recommend to start with unit tests. You might have to rewrite code a lot in order for it to be testable. (In other words, instead of trying tests to fit current legacy code, it's usually better to refactor the code to make it testable.)

Comment: Ruby 1.9 is **not** needed for a Rails 3 upgrade, even for Rails 3.2.

Comment: That might have applied when Rails 3.0 came out years back. Nowadays, you're practically screwed if you try it, even for later version of Rails 3.0 - I did, and after dealing with weird marshalling errors (which supposedly have only certain 1.8.7 revisions http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#rails-3-requires-at-least-ruby-1-8-7) I found out it's much less hassle to just upgrade to 1.9.3.

Comment: @LukasStejskal Yes I have trouble with my host and custom gems are my only options. I still need some time to fix and upgrade stuff. I'm only a 1 man team at the moment.